# React-bootstrap OverlayTrigger is not positioned correctly while container has overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've got a problem while rendering content using react-bootstrap (v1.0.0-beta.5). I have main container with list of buttons and every button is wrapped with OverlayTrigger (Tooltip in overlay). As there are many list items whole container must have 'overflow-x: auto', but it seems to break Tooltips/Overlays positioning (when I remove it from css, overlay is positioned just fine).

[image: I attached pic]

I attached a pic. As you can see tooltip is positioned on button instead of being at the top of it.

Can anyone help me with idea how to walk it around?

```
 .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

const editTooltip = <Tooltip id='edit_tooltip'>hello edit tooltip</Tooltip>;

<div className='container'>
   <div className='item-1'>
     <OverlayTrigger
       placement='top'
       overlay={editTooltip}
       delay={700}
      >
       <Button
         variant={'light'}
         bsPrefix={'custom-btn'}
         onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}
      >
        <Icon icon='pencil' />
      </Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ladyk, answers go down there. They don't belong in your question. See the edit history for a record of your solution and post a proper answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button a class name and place the button below the tooltip using the `margin` property.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```